# Importing and Exporting Module Variables - Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route of type `post`, that is receiving some info from the front-end, as shown below:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const UsernameController = require("../controllers/username.controller");

router.post("/username", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cookie = req.cookies;
    const {userName} = req.body;
    let allGames = await new UsernameController().getGames(userName);
    console.log(allGames[0].games)
    return res.sendStatus(200)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(422).send(err);
  };
});

module.exports = router;
```

I need to use the destructured `{userName} = req.body` in another file. So I’m wondering how I can export the `{userName}` received from the front-end to the `middleware.js` file.

**`middleware.js`**:

```
const AuthController = require("../controllers/auth.controller");
const UsernameController = require("../controllers/username.controller");
const usernameRouter = require('../routes/username.route')

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  let userName = usernameRouter.userName
  const userGamesArray = await new  UsernameController().getGames(userName)
  req.userGamesArray = userGamesArray;
  next();
};
```

When I console.log the userName variable in the middleware file, it responds with `undefined` which means I’m importing the variable wrongly from the `route.js` file.

Kindly assist me with importing the variable from the `route.js` file to the `middleware.js` file.

Comment: Why don't you also use `const {userName} = req.body;` in this middleware?

Comment: hey @Anatoly, It won't work because the middleware file doesn't have access to `req.body`coming from the front-end.Only `router.post("/username", async (req, res)` has access to `req.body`. Forgot to mention that the route.js file and the middleware.js file are 2 separate files.

Comment: Any middleware has access to `req` and `res` and you defined it correctly ` async (req, res, next) => {`

Comment: I see. I've tried using `const {userName} = req.body;` like you suggested, but the result is still `userName undefined`. `userName` is working just fine in the router.js file, as it is coming straight from the front-end, but, it's `undefined` inside the middleware.js file.

Comment: If this middleware is also working with `/username` then `req.body.userName` also should be available.

Comment: Kindly assist me with making `/username` work with the middleware file, if it's not too much to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a middleware in this `/username` route like this:

```js
const middleware = require("./middleware"); // correct this path to a real one

router.post("/username", middleware, async (req, res) => {
...
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Now working as expected.